# Conditioning X jointly on two independent variables Y and Z

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For events $A$, $B$, and $C$, suppose we know that $A\perp C$ and $A\perp B$ such that probability $P(A|B)=P(A)$ and $P(A|C)=P(A)$. Does it follow that $P(A|B\cap C)=P(A)$?

Comment: Please explain downvote? This is not a homework problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not necessarily. Consider the following well known example from Bernstein (1928).

Suppose a box contains four tickets labelled 112, 121, 211,
222. Choose one ticket at random and consider the events $$A = \{1 \text{ occurs in the first
place}\},$$ $$B = \{1 \text{ occurs in the second place}\},$$ $$C= \{ 1 \text{ occurs in the third place}\}.$$

Here $P(A|B)=P(A)=\frac{1}{2}$ and  $P(A|C)=P(A)=\frac{1}{2}$ but $P(A|B\cap C)=0$.

Comment: I like this example because events $B$ and $C$ here are independent with each other as well.

Comment: I wonder about how many people wrongly think of 'independence of the past given the present' in the definition of the Markov property exactly this way: since $A$ is independent of $C$, one could also think that $\mathbb{P}(A|B\cap C)=\mathbb{P}(A|B)$. This counterexample also shows that this is also false, and the Markov property is not as intuitive as it is always made look. The process forgets the past in the present, by definition, it is not independent of it.